# Matlab: Inconsistency in numbering pattern of legend entries

Tags: matlab, legend, printf, multiple-entries

I am plotting multiple lines inside a loop using `hold(Ax, 'on')`. To manage the legend updating each time a new line is added, I am appending my legends as:

`reshape(sprintf('Zone #%02d',1:ii), 8, ii)'`

Where `ii` is the loop iteration counter. This produces the legend entries as `Zone #01`, `Zone #02`, `Zone #03` etc.
Now, instead of above entries, I want to produce the legend entries as `Zone # 1 and 2 Intersection`, `Zone # 2 and 3 Intersection`, `Zone # 3 and 4 Intersection` etc. To get this pattern I did something like `reshape(sprintf('Zone # %01d and %01d Intersection', 1:ii, 2:ii + 1), 27, ii)`, but it messes up the consistency in numbering pattern if `ii` is greater than `3` as shown below:

[image]

Can you spot where am I going wrong? Thanks as always!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - the way Matlab interprets your statement, it will first "consume" the entire first array, then the second. So if you say

```
sprintf('%d %d ', 1:5, 2:6)
```

the output will be

```
1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6
```

It just so happens that you are getting it "almost right" for a little bit because of the way you were trying to do things and that became confusing.

The correct way to achieve what you want is make sure that the order in which variables are consumed by matlab is the order you need.  An example of doing this would be

```
sprintf('%d %d ', [1:3; 2:4])
```

When matlab accesses the array you created

```
1 2 3
2 3 4
```

It does so by going down the colums - so it sees

```
1 2 2 3 3 4
```

To generate the legend you want, use

```
reshape(sprintf('Zone # %01d and %01d Intersection', [1:ii; 2:ii + 1]), 27, ii)'
```

Which results in

```
Zone # 1 and 2 Intersection
Zone # 2 and 3 Intersection
Zone # 3 and 4 Intersection
Zone # 4 and 5 Intersection
Zone # 5 and 6 Intersection
```

for `ii = 5` . Note I transposed the output of the `reshape` to achieve this (that's the `'` at the end of the line)